# Twist Text-Effect

Tags: animation, modifiers, text-object

I want to transform a text as seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgBwmTTpark&index=26&list=PL-QUX2ESuZtKJBnkdTOvjJ5eupC7xDYb8) from 0:00 to 0:03.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Curve modifier

If you don't mind the letters being deformed, then you can use a curve modifier:

1. Add a path (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Curve > Path*) and change the tilt of the last control vertex to 90°
   (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>><kbd>90</kbd>)
2. Add a curve modifier to the text and select the path as the object.

   [image]
3. Animate the path object sliding past.

   [image]

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That's what I was searching for. I didn't know how to rotate a Vertex of a path. Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

Check out these two amazing addons by Atom:

[[AddOn] RE:Lay (Updated For Blender 2.66)](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?219404-AddOn-RE-Lay-%28Updated-For-Blender-2-66%29)

[[AddOn] RE:Phrase+ 1.3 for Blender 2.6.1 (CAPs,Kerning and More!)](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?245115-AddOn-RE-Phrase-1-3-for-Blender-2-6-1-%28CAPs-Kerning-and-More!%29)

Comment: ok thanks, i will check that in about three hours. Do you also have an idea how to do the whole thing without add-ons?

Comment: Ok, I've checked out the RE:Lay Add-On and it is really cool. Thanks a lot! Also for other things!